# polkit rule is not working

Tags: polkit

```
policykit-1 version 0.105-17
```

I cannot seem to make the policykit rule work. All I want is to let anyone be able to run `systemctl daemon-reload` in the system (for test purposes).

I found the action name for this task from the file `org.freedesktop.systemd1.policy` as `org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon`. I have dropped in a simple rule as following:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/01-umut.rules

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon") {
                    return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
});
```

I am expecting this rule to allow anyone run this action but that is not the case.

I have run policykit form the command line as `sudo /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd` and used `polkit.log("Hello my rule");` in my rule just to see if the rule ever gets executed and no luck there either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

If `PolKit` version < `0.106`, there are **no** `.rules` files but only old `.pkla` and `.conf` files.

You can check version of `Polkit` by: `pkaction --version`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the version I am using has a bug. I have switched to 0.113-5 version on debian and it worked like charm.