# systemd service management using pkla equivalents to polkit's rules on Debian

Tags: debian, systemd, polkit

I'm trying to allow users of a `somegroup` to manage `someunit` systemd service.

In `polkit (>=0.106)`, this can be done by adding rules:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/20-someunit.rules
---
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" 
        && subject.isInGroup("somegroup")
        && (action.lookup("unit") == "someunit.service") )
    {
        var verb = action.lookup("verb");
        if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
});
```

However, I'm on Debian stretch/buster where we have been on `polkit 0.105` since 2012.  `polkit(<0.106)` doesn't support the `rules.d/*` files.  Instead, we rely on `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/*.pkla`.

Following some examples in [pklocalauthority(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pklocalauthority), I'm able to get most of this working in an equivalent pkla file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/manage-units.pkla
----
[Allow users to manage services]
Identity=unix-group:somegroup
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
```

However, this grants access for ALL actions on ALL services.  Is there an equivalent to permitting specific `action.lookup()` features?

I did try out `systemctl enable` and `systemctl edit`, of which both still failed (that's good).  So `action.lookup("verb")` may not be required, but `action.lookup("unit")` is still quite important.

There are a lot of unanswered questions on this subject:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/536591
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/875522
- [polkit rule is not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not possible. This feature was implemented for the .rules-variant only

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/1159

Answer (score -1):

works for a user though:

```
sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/54-manage-units.pkla
[systemd]
Identity=unix-user:pi
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

In fact, it was the only way to make it work on raspian, because it doesn't honor the polkit rules written in javascript from some strange reason.

Comment: Hi, your answer doesn't seem to answer OP's question at all. I don't see anything limiting the policy to a particular service (`someunit.service`) or action (start/stop/restart). As far as I can see, your answer makes it possible to do anything to any service, which OP explicitly does not want. (I will remove my downvote once the answer gets improved.)

Comment: You are right that's it's too relaxed and may be a security risk and it's not answering the original question per-se, but it can be useful for people who want to achieve systemctl start foo w/o using sudo on raspian. I was looking how to do that and that's how I find this question. It took me like 2 hours to find out that raspian doesn't support the polkit rules and this is actually the only way around it. Do whatever you want w/ your downvotes :)